# TortoiseSVN working copy multiple access

Tags: tortoise-svn

I have workstation that multiple users can login and use. We have configuration files in a working copy in a  public directory that are version controlled on that workstation.
The idea would be that each user could login with their own domain account make a change to that working copy and commit and each users changes would be tracked.
Having a separate working copy for each user is not acceptable as the program that runs needs those configuration files. THe versioned files do not change often but when they do we want to keep track of who changed them.
TortoiseSVN runs into problems when multiple accounts access a working copy created with a different account. Any suggestions on how we could make this work?

Answer (score 0):

> Having a separate working copy for each user is not acceptable as the
>   program that runs needs those configuration files.

No. Technically you are wrong, and you *can* have "WC-per-user" and this is **The Easiest Way (tm)**, but, sadly, not **The Cutest Way (tm)**: just create personal WCs and (post-commit?) (client-side?) hooks in order to copy files from WC|Repo to final destination

> Any suggestions on how we could make this work?

As usual in "Windows with multi-user". Check permissions of any file|directory, created by $USER in $USERGROUP on host. Without additional tricks, you'll see (I can't check for $DOMAINUSER, but do not expect a fundamental difference with $LOCALUSER): owner is $USER with full set of rights, $USERGROUP (to which belong *all* users) have only `READ`+ `READ&EXECUTE` in "Allow" permissions (no WRITE, which is a must for work with WC). Solution is (AFAICS) obvious: after creating "shared" WC change owner of WC to the group of all users OR give group WRITE permissions for the WC-tree